# Why say panel and boxlayout twice?

Tags: java, swing, layout

```
panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
```

Comment: panel could most likely be replaced with "Box panel = Box.createVerticalBox();" in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `BoxLayout` is easy - the argument (`Y_AXIS`) to the `BoxLayout` constructor belongs to the `BoxLayout` class so you need to specify that. There may well be another `Y_AXIS` value which would be the wrong one to use.

This is the basis of encapsulation.

With regards to the `panel` double-mention, I can't be sure. But it seems plausible that the panel needs to be told what its layout manager is *and* the layout manager needs to know which panel it's applied to (since it needs to know the contents of the panel in order to lay them out intelligently).

Comment: Not sure, I'm satisified with that answer (on the panel double mention). It isn't so for other layout managers and since the setLayout() method belongs the panel object itself, that should be enough, just like it's done for other layout managers... Thus I prefer Gregory Mostizky's answer

Answer (score 1):

The `panel` arguement to `BoxLayout` is somewhat confusing.  You need to specify the target that the `BoxLayout` instance is attached to.  Further, in many methods based on the `LayoutManager2` Interface, `BoxLayout` requires the `panel` to be passed in and it performs a check that you have passed in the right one.

The Y_AXIS is a class variable that is one of two legal int values for the orientation of the `BoxLayout`.  You could just pass in the value 0, but using the constant is much better.

Answer (score 1):

Well mostly because BoxLayout is an old API before they knew any better.

Use [MigLayout](http://www.miglayout.com/) if you are interested in a good flexible modern layout manager